# How to assign Typescript function signature to named functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, conventions

When using typescript, I tend to write my functions in this pattern:

```
const myFunc: MyFuncType = (input, otherInput, moreInput) => {
  return input + otherInput + moreInput;
};
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass an interface to a named function.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
function myFunc<MyFuncType>(input, otherInput, moreInput) {
  return input + otherInput + moreInput;
}
```

In that second example, Typescript assigns `any` to all my function parameters, instead of inferring the type of each parameter. Is the `const` pattern the only way to assign a function signature?

Thanks.

Comment: the syntax you tried is generics syntax and has nothing to do about type annotation. To ascribe type annotation to function declaration, you will have to annotate the input separately and the output, eg: add(a:number, b:number): number {}

Comment: you could do `const myFunc: MyFuncType = function myFunc (...) { ... }` but I know that's a bit annoying. Not sure there's another way around it.

Comment: For those reviewing the request to re-open, the answers linked do not answer this question. I am able to answer this question correctly once re-opened

Comment: That question was not open, until now... I will answer

Comment: @Blowsie Ah, I didn't realise the other question had been closed as well. I'll close this one again as a duplicate of the one where you posted your answer